# RPG Stack Exchange D&D 5th Edition Contest - Dungeon Master's Guide Edition

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

> ### All Raffles Now Completed
>
> Thanks to everyone who participated! **466 questions were asked by 172 users across the months that this contest ran**. Thanks also go to those who answered all of these questions - each and every question asked has received an answer, very many of which were highly in-depth. I'd say our goal of building a knowledge base for the new system has been a rousing success.
>
> This post will eventually be updated with various statistics about participation in the event as a whole.

As has been hinted at across many posts in Meta, 5th Edition of Dungeons & Dragons is coming out soon! To lead us into this, we've sent 3 advance copies to 3 users selected amongst those voted by your community. So let us begin by congratulating the winners - [DampeS8N](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3799/dampes8n), [Joshua Aslan Smith](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3529/joshua-aslan-smith), and [Oblivious Sage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3548/oblivious-sage)!

The naming is not just for congratulations, but also to give y'all a heads up. As we're approaching the official release, I have asked these 3 to help begin populating the site with questions about 5th edition. If there's one thing that's better than having questions on our site at the start of the launch, it's having good questions before anyone else gets their hands on it. That way, those who buy it on release, they can already find us as a place to get answers to their questions, and may already find them without needing to ask. So keep aware that these three folks have these advance copies and will be asking questions early.

Which brings us to our contest. **We will be raffling out copies of the 3 core rulebooks as each one is released**. It's a simple process - ask good questions that get upvoted about 5th edition, and you'll earn one chance at winning one of the books. The more you ask, the more chances you'll have. There will be 4 separate raffles.

- From the release of the starter box to the release of the Player's Handbook, users will earn a chance to win a copy of the PHB when it comes out.
- From the release of the PHB until the release of the Monster Manual, users will earn a chance to win a copy of the MM when it comes out.
- From the release of the MM until the release of the Dungeon Master's Guide, users will earn a chance to win a copy of the DMG when it comes out.
- A bonus raffle will be held for our 3 folks who are helping pre-populate our site with wonderful content. For the upvoted questions they ask leading up to the release of the starter box, they will earn chances to win a copy of the Player's Handbook as well.

I look forward to celebrating our ability to take a unique part in welcoming the new edition of D&D to the world at large. Let's start a grand new adventure here, together!

Comment: Which release date are you'd using for the Starter Set, the 3rd or the 15th? (WotC is doing a two-step release for all of these, first through partner program stores, then a wider release.)

Comment: @Seven We're going for the 15th.

Comment: @GMNoob If the DMG comes out after the MM then we'll swap the two in that case. I had heard otherwise but I may be listening to the wrong channels on that one. Basically the raffles will follow the release order.

Comment: How does the raffle work? 1 [upvote|answer|question] = 1 ticket? And are tickets from the first part discarded for the second?

Comment: For some more exact release dates, [I believe this list on ENWorld is up-to-date](http://www.enworld.org/forum/content.php?1631-Dungeons-Dragons-Starter-Set-Fantasy-Roleplaying-Fundamentals-%28D-D-Boxed-Game%29-Hits-Amazon!#.U8CQl7F9t94). Barring delays, of course.

Comment: @corsiKa 1 "ticket" per upvoted question. At the moment, we're not looking at rolling tickets over but that might change as we observe how the question pileup goes.

Comment: cool, thanks #ruleslawyer

Comment: quick question here, in case that someone outside USA won, can that person claim the prize in PDF form?

Comment: @bomberclaw I don't believe they've released any plans for PDF versions of any of the books. WOTC is much more pro-pdf in the last year or so but I have to assume that any PDF versions of the PHB, DMG, and MM will be released next year if at all.

Comment: @GraceNote Didn't know a better way to reach you, tried emailing. I still haven't received either book I won. I wanted to confirm that they have shipped or if not what the status was and double check my address that they shipped to.

Comment: @Joshua Huh, let me check on that today then.

Comment: @GraceNote Email me whatever you find out, thanks.

Comment: @Joshua Any updates? Did they arrive yet?

Answer (score 7):

The first raffle period has closed! Thanks to everyone who participated in it! In total, **98 upvoted questions from 47 users** were generated in the time period, for 98 total tickets earned. An interesting observation from this, **36% of question askers (17 in total) were newly registered at some point after July 15th**, which is a pretty healthy amount of new volume.

I wanted to do the drawing as soon as a tabulated the tickets, but seeing as the chatrooms were all but empty at the time, I've decided to hold off the drawing by a day so that we can get some witnesses and more importantly excitement! I will also be drawing the winner of the bonus raffle at the time.

> **The drawing was held in [the Fifth Edition Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17249772#17249772) at about 17:00 UTC (1:00 PM EDT) on Wednesday**. The drawing was done with a simulated 1d100 (via 2d10) in accordance to [this results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5amUW.png). The bonus drawing was done with a simulated 1d5 (via 1d10) with Joshua as the first 3/5 and Oblivious as the latter 2/5.

Congratulations to **[rampion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/541/rampion)** for winning the raffle for the PHB! And to **[Joshua Aslan Smith](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3529/joshua-aslan-smith)** for winning the bonus raffle. Emails should go out later with forms to fill out for receiving your prizes.

Answer (score 4):

The second raffle period has closed! Thanks to everyone who participated in it! In total, **171 upvoted questions from 70 users** were generated in the time period. Let's check out some statistics on those numbers!

- **18 users who participated in the first raffle** participated in the second raffle, and contributed **60 questions between them**.
- Of the above numbers, **4 users who were newly registered from July 15th** submitted **20 of those questions**.
- **52 users who were not present in the first raffle** participated in this raffle, and contributed **111 questions between them**. This accounts for **74% of users participating in this raffle being newly active in this tag**.
- **25 of those users were newly registered on August 19th or later**, and those users accounted for **55 of the questions asked**. This means that **almost 50% of the new boost in both users and questions came from people who newly registered after the release of the PHB**. These new users ranged from users who contributed several questions (including one user contributing 24 questions) to users who contributed only one or two questions but went on to stick around as strong answerers.

> **The drawing was held in [the Fifth Edition Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17923682#17923682) at about 17:00 UTC (1:00 PM EDT) on Tuesday**. The drawing was done using a simulated 1d216 (via 3d6, converted from base 6 to base 10), in accordance to [this gigantic results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Bjz.png).

Congratulations to **[Joshua Aslan Smith](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3529/joshua-aslan-smith)** for winning the raffle for the MM, to go hand-in-hand with his new PHB! An email should go out later regarding the receiving of your prize.

Answer (score 3):

The third and final raffle period has closed! Thanks to everyone who participated, not just in this round but in any of the rounds! It's been a wonderful run for this contest.

For the third raffle period, **197 upvoted questions from 93 users** were generated. I'll have more detailed statistics on not just the participation in this round in this post, and statistics for the contest as a whole will be in the main post.

> **The drawing was held in [the Fifth Edition Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18999236#18999236) at about 19:00 UTC (2:00 PM EST) on Wednesday**. The drawing was done once again using a simulated 1d216 via 3d6 in base 6, using [this results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQXD9.png).

Congratulations to **[Nicholas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/16414/nicholas)** for winning the raffle for the DMG! An email should be going out to you shortly regarding your prize.